# input file no me reconoce el tipo 'application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey' en Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

¡Hola!, tengo un componente para un `input file` para cargar archivos `.cer` y `.key`.

El problema que tengo es que no me reconoce la extensión  **application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey**  y el `tipo` de documento me lo devuelve como un `string vacío`.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
onFileChange(event, idDocument) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.validFileType === 'cer' && file.type !== 'application/x-x509-ca-cert') {
      swal('Formato de archivo inválido', 'Sólo puedes subir archivos .cert', 'error');
      return;
    } else if (this.validFileType === 'key' && file.type !== 'application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey') {
      swal('Formato de archivo inválido', 'Sólo puedes subir archivos .key', 'error');
      return;
    }

    if (file.size > 15000000) {
      swal('Tamaño no permitido', 'Sólo puedes subir archivos con un tamaño máximo de 15MB', 'error');
      return;
    }

    this.filename = file.name;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group mt-3 mb-0 display-inline-block">
  <input type="file" name="{{ name }}" id="{{ name }}" class="inputfile form-control-file display-hidden" (change)="onFileChange($event, name)" accept=".{{ validFileType }}" />
  <a class="{{ style }}" (click)="openFileBrowser($event, name)">
    <span class="text-bold-300">{{ inputMessage }}</span>
  </a>
  {{ filename }}
</div>
```

[image: Clave privada .key]

Sin embargo, con el `tipo` de archivo `.cer`, sí me devuelve el tipo de extensión:

[image: Certificado .cer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi caso, usando Chrome Beta 68 en Ubuntu 18.04, sí me reconoce **un archivo cualquiera** con extensión `.key` como `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso te dice dos cosas

1. El problema depende de tu sistema operativo y browser. Y si logras solucionarlo, puede que para tus usuarios finales no funcione.
2. Si me bastó con cambiar la extensión de un archivo cualquiera para que el browser diagnosticara esa extensión, es porque el browser no hace ninguna validación de lo que le pusiste en el input. Sólo hace match de la extensión con un listado interno.

En otras palabras: bastaría con dejarlo pasar si el archivo tiene extensión `.key`.

## Validar el mime-type real de un archivo antes de subirlo

Si realmente quisieras validar el mimetype, también se puede, usando un objeto [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Alimentas al FileReader con el contenido del input, lo lees como un ArrayBuffer, y una vez hecho esto, detectas sus "magic numbers", que son sus primeros 4 bytes en hexadecimal. Prueba el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("archivo").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
 var files = document.getElementById("archivo").files;
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
  console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
  console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
 }

 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
  var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
  var header = [];
  arr.forEach(function (chunk) {
   chunk = chunk.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').toUpperCase();
   header.push(chunk);
  });
  console.log('magic numbers', header.join(' '));


 };
 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);

}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="archivo">
```

Hay bases de datos ([incluso wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)) donde puedes averiguar qué significa cada combinación de magic numbers. Por ejemplo, si subes un PDF, los magic numbers serán [25 50 44 46](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=25%2050%2044%2046&mode=SIG). En un JPG, serán [FF D8 FF E0](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=FFD8FFE0&mode=SIG).

Pero aquí viene lo más jodido:

1. No siempre basta con 4 bytes para diagnosticar un archivo
2. Una gran variedad de archivos que el browser reconoce como distintos tienen magic numbers que coinciden con la firma de un archivo zip. Todos los ODS, XLSX, DOCX, KMZ y muchos otros, son en realidad archivos zipeados.

Haz la prueba subiendo un archivo `.key` válido en mi ejemplo, mira sus magic numbers, búscalos en google y si no calzan con un zip, lotería.

Comment: ¡muchas gracias! :)