# move_uploaded_file subir archivo con restricción

Tags: php, codeigniter, fileupload, upload

Tengo este código en `php framework codeigniter` estuve gooleando como hacer que solo suba archivos `pdf` y `doc`. No tuve resultado si me pueden ayudar.

```
function insert_accountant(){
$page_data = array(     // array data that postulate the input fileds
  'name'                => $this->input->post('name'),
  'accountant_number'   => $this->input->post('accountant_number'),
  'address'             => $this->input->post('address'),
  'phone'           => $this->input->post('phone'),
  'marital_status'  => $this->input->post('marital_status'),
);

$page_data['file_name'] = $_FILES["file_name"]["name"];
$page_data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
$check_email = $this->db->get_where('accountant', array('email' => $page_data['email']))->row()->email; // checking if email exists in database

if($check_email != null) {
  $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message', get_phrase('email_already_exist'));
  redirect(base_url() . 'admin/accountant/', 'refresh');
} else {
  $this->db->insert('accountant', $page_data);
  $librarian_id = $this->db->insert_id();
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/accountant_image/" . $_FILES["file_name"]["name"]); // upload files
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/accountant_image/' . $librarian_id . '.jpg');            // image with user ID
  //$this->email_model->account_opening_email('accountant', $data['email']); //Send email to receipient email adddrress upon account opening
} }
```

Comment: Debes colocar el error que te está arrojando.

Answer (score 1):

Bien puedes validar con JavaScript para que solo se permitan los tipos de archivo que tu decidas o bien también con PHP:

Para ello utilizaría la matriz $_FILES, que te proporciona $_FILES['type'], donde se define el tipo de fichero que intentas subir, y luego con un if-else puede asegurarte que se suba el tipo de archivo que deseas:

```
if($_FILES['archivo']['type']=="application/pdf" && $_FILES['archivo']['type']=="otros tipos de archivos") { 
  //Código 
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero tuve que cambiar el operador "&&" que es "and" por un operador que sea "or"

Answer (score 0):

En el formulario de front puedes filtrar el tipo de archivos que acepta el input

```
<input type="file"
   id="documento" name="documento"
   accept="application/pdf, application/msword, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing">
```

Pero nada impide que un usuario suba -por ejemplo- una foto a la cual haya cambiar la extensión de PNG a DOCX.

Dado que el browser infiere el tipo mime del archivo usando la extensión, y la extensión puede ser modificada arbitrariamente, lo que se envía al backend sufre del mismo problema. Esa foto renombrada llegará a la superglobal $_FILES con el mime type que le informó el browser.

La manera correcta es en realidad usar los magic bytes. La cabecera del archivo, cuando se lee como binario, permite saber qué contiene realmente:

```
$mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES["documento"]["tmp_name"]);
```

En otra respuesta de este sitio [respondí a algo similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227379/como-evitar-que-suban-archivos-shell-o-ataques-de-archivos-en-php/227393#227393) (pero ahí utilicé la función `finfo_type` que es parte de la extensión FileInfo)