# Como puedo instanciar una variable de tipo File de un fichero existente para codificar su contenido?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Me explico, se me ha presentado un problema al tratar de instanciar una variable File de un archivo ya existente en un servidor del trabajo. La forma en que lo he realizado es la siguiente

```
var file = new File("H:/OT/PROYECTOS/pdf1.pdf");
```

Haciendo lo anterior en la consola salta un error avisando de que el constructor utilizado no es el correcto. Estuve mirando información sobre el constructor de la clase File y probé entonces lo siguiente:

```
var file = new File([""], "H:/OT/PROYECTOS/pdf1.pdf");
```

De esta manera ya no se quejaba de que el constructor no era el correcto, pero no comprendo que es lo que supone ese otro campo que he agregado. Igualmente desconozco si de esa forma estoy creando una instancia de ese fichero ya existente en mi máquina o es otro completamente nuevo.

Esto lo digo por que lo que busco yo es recuperar el fichero en cuestión para así entonces poder recuperar el contenido de este y hacerle un encode a base64.

La parte de codificarlo a base64 y después recuperar el contenido ya codificado, he probado a hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
function convertToBase64(file) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var base64;
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        console.log(base64);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return base64;
}
```

Este lo cogí de internet tras un rato de búsqueda, entiendo que por lo tanto esta variable file que se le pasa, ha de ser una instancia de la clase File y no la simple ruta de este, dado que si no se quejará entonces de que requiere de una instancia de la clase Blob cuando trabajamos con el FileReader.

Por lo tanto cual sería la forma correcta de recuperar ese fichero que existe en mi máquina local?

La idea que engloba a todo esto es la siguiente:
Necesito abrir un archivo local en el navegador para de esa forma visualizarlo en una nueva pestaña de Chrome.
La cosa es que debido a una medida de seguridad de los navegadores, no se permite abrir los archivos locales directamente, si no que estos se han de encontrar dentro del servidor de la página (cosa que en este caso, por temas de cantidad de datos, no me es posible).
Por lo tanto tras buscar un rato se me ocurrió la idea de codificar los datos de este archivo en base64, para así mas tarde en una nueva pestaña con un iframe, decodificarlo de nuevo para poder visualizarlo.

El código de lo que he estado tratando de hacer es el siguiente:

```
function verimagen() {
    var file = new File([""], "H:/OT/PROYECTOS/773/pdf1.PDF");
    var base64;
    getBase64(file).then(
        data => base64 = data   
    );
    
    console.log(base64);    // este log me muestra un "undefined"
    
    let pdfWindow = window.open("");
    pdfWindow.document.write(
        "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
        encodeURI(base64) + "'></iframe>"
    );
}

function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

No se si el código anterior es correcto o todo este proceso de codificado y visualizado en una nueva pestaña se podría hacer de otra manera.

La cuestión es que estos archivos que estoy buscando mostrar en una nueva pestaña, se encuentran en una máquina diferente pero ubicada en la misma red, por la cual cosa puedo tener una unidad de red agregada que me hace referencia a ella (en este caso es la unidad H:). También podría acceder a ella mediante la sintaxis **\\servidor\carpeta...**. En esta otra máquina es donde se ubican todas las imágenes a las cuales necesito acceder, y yo recuperaré la ruta de estas mediante otro proceso que recupera esta información de la base de datos que esta siendo utilizada.

Por lo tanto la cuestión es que tampoco puedo hacer uso de un `<input type="file"/>` por que no es algo que el usuario me deba facilitar, si no que es un recurso local al cual yo necesito acceder para de esa forma facilitarlo al usuario.

En la página web dispongo tanto de **PHP** como **jQuery**, para dar mas posibles soluciones.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, desde el tema de la creación de la instancia File, hasta posibles sugerencias al código utilizado. Gracias.

Comment: La documentación de [File()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) solo está disponible en inglés, pero es muy clara respecto a que el primer parámetro es el contenido del archivo y, el segundo, el nombre. Es decir, sirve para **crear** un nuevo objeto de tipo `file` especificando contenido, tipo, etc. **No funciona para leer archivos existentes**.

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta PHP, te sirve una opción del lado del servidor? Si el usuario bajo el que corre PHP tiene acceso a la carpeta podrías usar [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando con PHP, he probado con el [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php), pero me mostraba caracteres que js no acababa de aceptarme. He continuado buscando y entonces he encontrado [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) y ha sido con esta función con la que al final he logrado dar con una solución a toda la problemática. Gracias por la sugerencia de utilizar el propio php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he logrado llegar a una forma para rodear la alerta de seguridad y así poder mostrar archivos que se encuentren alojados localmente en la máquina.

Para llevarlo a cabo al final he terminado por hacer uso de la función `file_get_contents(ruta)` de **PHP** para recuperar el contenido del archivo en cuestión. Posteriormente le hago un enconde a base64 también desde el propio PHP con la función `base64_encode("string")`.

Una vez tenia el contenido del fichero codificado en base64 dentro de **PHP**, lo he llevado al **JavaScript** mediante un `<?php echo $variable ?>` en la asignación de la variable de js.

Una vez tenia ya la variable en js con el contenido codificado del fichero, lo único que restaba era decoficarlo a la hora de mostrarlo en una nueva pestaña. Para mostrar el contenido de la cadena de datos decofidicada, he hecho uso de un elemento iframe:

`<iframe src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(variable) + '></iframe>"`

Donde `variable` es el String de js codificado.

Todos estos fragmentos de código se encuentran dentro del mismo fichero **.php**. Finalmente el código utilizado total es el siguiente en orden:

### HTML:

```
<button onclick="verImagen(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="verImagen(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="verImagen(3)">3</button>
<button onclick="verImagen(4)">4</button>
```

### PHP:

```
<?php
    $img1 = "";
    $img2 = "";
    $img3 = "";
    $img4 = "";

    if ($treeRes->tImg1 != "") {
        $img1 = file_get_contents('\\\server\carpeta'.$treeRes->tImg1);
        $img1 = base64_encode($img1);
    }
    if ($treeRes->tImg2 != "") {
        $img2 = file_get_contents('\\\server\carpeta'.$treeRes->tImg2); 
        $img2 = base64_encode($img2);
    }
    if ($treeRes->tImg3 != "") {
        $img3 = file_get_contents('\\\server\carpeta'.$treeRes->tImg3);
        $img3 = base64_encode($img3);
    }
    if ($treeRes->tImg4 != "") {
        $img4 = file_get_contents('\\\server\carpeta'.$treeRes->tImg4);
        $img4 = base64_encode($img4);
    }
?>
```

En mi caso las variables `$treeRes->tImg1, $treeRes->tImg2, $treeRes->tImg3...` hacen referencia a las diferentes rutas de los ficheros que he recuperado desde la base de datos. partiendo desde la carpeta **\\server\carpeta**.

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    function verimagen(num) {
        var base64;
        
        switch (num) {
            case 1:
                base64 = '<?php echo $img1; ?>';
                break;
            case 2:
                base64 = '<?php echo $img2; ?>';
                break;
            case 3:
                base64 = '<?php echo $img3; ?>';
                break;
            case 4:
                base64 = '<?php echo $img4; ?>';
                break;
        }
        
        let pdfWindow = window.open("");
        pdfWindow.document.write(
            "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " +
            encodeURI(base64) + "'></iframe>"
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Una solución creativa y por sobre todo funcional. Recuerda eso sí no ponerla disponible para todo público, porque es potencialmente un "acceso directo" a la intranet

Comment: Es una plataforma que se encuentra disponible únicamente para los trabajadores de la empresa dentro de la red local de esta, por lo tanto no existe gran peligro respecto ese tema. Gracias por el aviso!

Comment: Me he dado cuenta después de realizar pruebas que este método tiene sus limitaciones, mientras se trate de archivos los cuales son de un tamaño reducido no debería haber problema, sin embargo a la que el tamaño de este incrementa si se supera un límite el proceso falla. No se cual es exactamente este limite, pero yo me he encontrado que en el caso de un archivo de 4mb, la cadena de cifrado que se utilizaba superaba el límite de longitud, y que por lo tanto el contenido del fichero se quedaba incompleto y no se podía recuperar.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos problemas conceptuales en tu planteamiento. En lo medular:

1. Un browser no puede interactuar unilateralmente con el sistema de archivos de un visitante. Se prestaría para uso malicioso por decir lo menos.
2. El constructor del objeto [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) espera un blob (o un buffer, dependiendo del contexto) o sea el contenido binario del archivo. El segundo parámetro es el nombre y un tercer parámetro opcional permite especificar su mime type, que es arbitrario y cero fidedigno. Ninguno de esos parámetros corresponde a la ruta física del archivo en el equipo del visitante.

El ejemplo que viste para leer como dataUrl es correcto y podría ser lo que buscas si pasamos por alto el tamaño. Lo único que te falta es que, en vez de intentar leer directo del equipo del visitante, debes ofrecerle [un input de tipo `file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) o instanciar un objeto [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) para que el usuario elija un archivo local (o varios) o lo arrastre a un contenedor.

Lo importante es que sólo obtendrás el contenido de ese archivo como consecuencia de una acción del usuario. Esa acción gatillará un evento, y si tenías un listener sobre éste, podrás obtener el contenido del archivo como una propiedad del evento.
Por ejemplo, acá estoy leyendo el contenido de una imagen, la paso a base64 y la inserto en la página:

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file_input"),
  divFotos = document.getElementById("fotos");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let conjuntoDeArchivos = event.target.files,
    primerArchivo = conjuntoDeArchivos[0];
  console.log(primerArchivo);
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.target.result;
    img.title = primerArchivo.name;
    divFotos.appendChild(img);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(primerArchivo);

}, false);
```

```css
#fotos img {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" id="file_input" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
</div>
<div id="fotos"></div>
```

Si te fijas, solamente tengo acceso al archivo dentro del evento `change` del input.

```
 let conjuntoDeArchivos = event.target.files,
     primerArchivo = conjuntoDeArchivos[0];
```

Ese "primerArchivo" puede pasarse como parámetro a un objeto `FileReader` para que éste, a su vez, procese el contenido binario y lo devuelva como base64, resultado que a su vez se obtiene dentro de un evento.

**Para qué procesar una subida en el browser?**

Para los lectores en general: si bien los inputs de tipo File son muy comunes, no es tan común acceder al archivo cargado directo en el browser en vez de enviarlo al backend. Aunque puede parecer ineficiente, hay algunos escenarios que vale la pena mencionar.

Por ejemplo: el OP menciona que el tamaño del archivo no permite subirlo al servidor, y aunque mi primera impresión es que menos todavía podrá manejar el contenido como base64, que por definición siempre será más extenso que el original, luego pensé que es perfectamente posible que el servidor esté configurado con un upload máximo ridículamente bajo.

Otro ejemplo: puede tratarse de una app serverless conectada a una BBDD documental en donde sólo se puede guardar texto. El browser se encarga de pasarlo a base64.

Otro más: una aplicación para subir imágenes es mucho más amigable si te permite previsualizar lo que estás subiendo y te deja redimensionar y recortar. El browser es perfectamente capaz de ello y de optimizar el peso de la imágen usando resampling bilineal o bicúbico.

Finalmente, y aunque es harto rebuscado, [se puede verificar el tipo de archivo que el usuario está intentando subir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188563/input-file-no-me-reconoce-el-tipo-application-x-iwork-keynote-sffkey-en-angula/188589#188589), para no limitarse a creerle a la extensión.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo me temo que es algo que en mi caso no me solucionaría la problemática. Fallo mío por no figurarlo en la pregunta desde un inicio, pero la cuestión es que estos archivos son archivos los cuales yo dispongo en una máquina local en mi misma red, y recupero la ruta de estos desde la base de datos que utilizo. Entonces, no son archivos que los usuarios puedan o me deban facilitar, si no archivos que yo he de recuperar para de esa manera mostrar a los usuarios. Todo esto es una pantalla de un CRM donde recupero información de la base de datos y la muestro.

Comment: Ya veo. Pero en ese escenario la restricción se mantiene. Lo único que te queda es hacerte un mini-backend que pueda recuperar esos archivos para que el browser los muestre. Eso, o derechamente hacer una applicación de escritorio

Comment: Finalmente si que he logrado encontrar una solución a este problema, la he publicado como otra respuesta a la pregunta. Gracias por tu participación igualmente